# How to get a filename of copied email by procmail and pass it to a script?

Tags: linux, procmail

I'm trying to execute script when email arrives my server and pass its filename to that script. First part is done, procmail executes script each time an email arrives. Before executing script it copies email to the specific directory.

```
:0c
procmail-dir/
:0 fw
| /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/script.py
```

How can I get a filename/path to just saved email in procmail-dir and pass it to a script.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `LASTFOLDER` contains the file name where the latest message delivery took place.  It is exported to subprocesses, so you can access it from Python with `os.environ['LASTFOLDER']`, or, of course, pass it as a command-line argument with something like

```
:0fw
| python3 /path/to/script.py "$LASTFOLDER"
```

Python will still receive the message on standard input, so this requirement to pass a file name seems slightly dubious. (Also, set up your `PATH` so you don't have to spell out the location of `python3` explicitly every time.)